# drf_yasg manual parameters configuration

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, openapi, drf-yasg

I am working with drf_yasg for the very first time and I am curious to know what does IN_QUERY and the other options provided by OPENAPI do. I can't find an explanation for the purpose of these options in the documentation.

Comment: IN_QUERY means if you need query params in api then you can use thus

Answer (score 1):

basically these options let you override where swagger looks for values to put in documentation, for example,

```
openapi.Parameter(
   openapi.IN_PATH, # looks for the parameter in path(or url)
   ...
)

openapi.Parameter(
   openapi.IN_BODY, # looks for the parameter in the body
   ...
)

openapi.Parameter(
   openapi.IN_HEADER, # looks for the parameter in the header
   ...
)
```

...and so on. you can customize your documentation using these options.